# How to send mail with attachment in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

> THIS IS MY ATTEMPT I AM GETTING AN ERROR:
>
> My SendMail.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="border: 1px solid" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <b>Send Mail with Attachment using asp.net</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    From:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    To:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Subject:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Attach a file:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    Body:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Send" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> My SendMail.aspx.cs

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
            //mail.To.Add("amit_jain_online@yahoo.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
            mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            mail.Body = txtBody.Text;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //Attach file using FileUpload Control and put the file in memory stream
            if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, fileUpload1.FileName));
            }
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
             //Or Your SMTP Server Address

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
            nc.UserName="myusername@gmail.com";
            nc.Password="mypassword";
            smtp.Credentials = nc;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

> I am getting this Error dont know what to do:
>
> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The >server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   Learn more at

Comment: it's doesn't look like it attachment problem. check if your username or password is wrong, maybe send without attachment first...

Comment: i have checked without attachment...getting the same error...

Comment: check again your username and password, I don't see other problems

Answer (score 0):

Try port 465 instead of 587, please. 
If I remember correctly, gmail uses 587 for TLS and 465 for SSL.