# Correct VB.NET for attaching a file to an email on an ASP.NET contact form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a contact form, written in `html` and `ASP.NET`. I want to use `<asp:FileUpload>` to attach a file to the email that is generated by the contact form, but I simply don't know what the VB.NET to do this is. I'm not a natural `VB`'er so it's not a language I speak, and everything I do in the language comes from examples. The VB I have already is below, can anyone tell me what VB.NET I need and where to put it in the code I already have? (I have placed a folder in the `httpdocs` file called Uploads)

Thanks in advance.

My Code :

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class Contact_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim combinedBodyString As String

    combinedBodyString = txtDetails.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & "---------Details-------- " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & "Org Name:        " & vbTab
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & txtOrg.Text & vbCrLf
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & "Name: " & vbTab
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & txtName.Text & vbCrLf

    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & "Tel No: " & vbTab
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & txtTelephoneNumber.Text & vbCrLf
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & "eMail: " & vbTab
    combinedBodyString = combinedBodyString & txtEmailAddress.Text & vbCrLf



    sendmail(txtEmailAddress.Text, combinedBodyString)

    Response.Redirect("~/Enquiry-Complete.aspx")

End Sub
Private Sub sendmail(ByVal from As String, ByVal body As String)
    Dim mailservername As String = "relay.hostinguk.net"
    Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(from, "xxxx@xxxxxxxx.co.uk", "General Enquiry", body)
    Dim mailclient As New SmtpClient

    mailclient.Host = mailservername

    mailclient.Send(message)
    message.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from.... [How to send mail with attachment in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769723/how-to-send-mail-with-attachment-in-asp-net)

```
//Attach file using FileUpload Control and put the file in memory stream
If fileUpload1.HasFile Then
  message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, fileUpload1.FileName))
End If
```

Add this between `mailclient.Host = mailservername` and `mailclient.Send(message)`

I would also suggest using a stringbuilder instead of concatenating stings together.